# Change position of progressbar in code

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a progress bar which I create in code my activity.
This is code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 
// Progress bar message.
String progressBarMessage = "Loading, please wait...";
progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage(progressBarMessage);
// set the progress to be horizontal
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
// reset the bar to the default value of 0
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
// convert the text value to a integer
int maximum = 100;
// set the maximum value
progressDialog.setMax(maximum);
// display the progressbar
progressDialog.show();
```

As you can see position my progressbar is bottom. How I can change position this progressbar to 3/4 of my page? I want to move that position will be between center and bottom? Maybe can I setMarginTop, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// ...
progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = progressDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
wmlp.y = height / 4;
progressDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
// ...
```

Where `height` is an `int` value(the height of the screen) that you initialize in the `onCreate` method like this:

```
height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```