# How can I get positions(x, y) of progress bar in android?

Tags: android, position, progress-bar

I just want to get positions(x, y) of progress bar in android?
I can't find that at stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289329/change-position-of-progressbar-in-code

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
```

and/or:

```
getLocationInWindow().
```